# Converting .mov files to .mp4 using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

The conversion answers that I have seen on the web suggest using a -c option in the command line using FFmpeg.  However using Ubuntu 14.04 the `-c` option does not exist in FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.

Is there a newer version? If so how can I get it. Using `apt-get` it says that *this* is the newest version.

Answer (score 21):

For Ubuntu 16 (and higher?):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 output.mp4
```

I realize the question referred to Ubuntu 14. But since this is the top Google result I got when searching "mov to mp4 ubuntu", I figure it would be worth adding here.

Source: https://mrcoles.com/convert-mov-mp4-ffmpeg/

Comment: I doubt anyone wants MP2 audio in MP4. Use `aac` instead.

Comment: Well your command line is working however it is re-encoding the video and in my case I got 5 Mb/s instead of th 10 M b/s from the original. The solution is the following :
$ ffmpeg -i input.mov -codec copy -acodec mp2 output.mkv
which preserve the original video bit rate ...

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Ubuntu 14.04 does not have FFmpeg at all in the standard repositories, an issue that has been rectified in subsequent Ubuntu releases. If you are keen to use *default* 14.04 offerings you would be using `avconv` from `libav-tools`. Use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools libavcodec-extra-54
```

And then to simply *change containers* from mov to mp4:

```
avconv -i input.mov -codec copy output.mp4
```

If you would prefer a modern version of FFmpeg that fits in well with Trusty Tahr 14.04 (and I would recommend this path) there are 2 good choices:

1. Use Doug McMahon's great [Trusty Multimedia PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media)
2. Compile your own bleeding edge FFmpeg from [FFmpeg trac instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

Lots of good choices! For FFmpeg the command line is only slightly different:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -codec copy output.mp4
```

And that should solve your issue...

**Note:** In some cases it may be necessary to actually *convert* the audio and video codecs contained within the .mov container to fit better in the .mp4 container. Depends entirely on the makeup of the .mov file, in most cases `-codec copy` should suffice...

Comment: Instead of compiling, what about `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main`?

Comment: Indeed another great choice that I shall add in to my answer....

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu 16.04 I used kdenlive to convert Vitamania*.mov to Vitamania.mp4 (7Gb -> 0.5Gb) as follows:

- Project / Add clip
- Drag the clip to the video 1 timeline
- Project / Render
  (mp4, H264/ACC fast, video quality 20, audio quality 160)

It took 1.5 hours.