# What is the easiest way to convert files to an MP4?

Tags: video, conversion

I want to convert a MOV file to MP4 file. I have found many ways on YouTube, but in a fix which one will take less time.

Comment: [This answer from a few years back](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128185/1222991) is still valid today. Be sure to test a couple of different settings to ensure the video and audio quality matches your expectations, though.

Comment: You should define easy. You don't want to read endless manpages, then GUI may be easy. Do you want to do this to many files? Then a command line tool which you can use in a script would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is a good GUI based software for video conversion/transcoding and it should be available to install from the Ubuntu software store and most repositories. If you have lots of videos you can queue up multiple jobs and then leave it to process all of them.